# How to prohibit the auto completion at the beginning of a new line in Vim?

Tags: vim, tabs, indentation, completion

In vim, after input the first several letters of a word,  I will use Tab key to activate the string completion.

But for one case, at the beginning of a new line, I want to use tab to input a intent. But my vim still to activate the completion, and pup out a completion menu.

So how to config the vim to just input a intent at the beginning of a new line.

Comment: Did you tried pressing tab twice?

Comment: After pessing tab twice, I just get the second word on the pop menu.

Comment: [Take a look at how VimCompletesMe does it](https://github.com/ajh17/VimCompletesMe/blob/master/plugin/VimCompletesMe.vim#L43). Or, simply, use it.

Comment: @romainl : why not posting this as an answer? Anyway, question need answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make vim indent automatically on new line, you can set the `autoindent` flag, see `:help autoindent`

The tab key by default inserts the tab character in insert mode. If you would like to use string completion while still being able to insert tab characters, you could remove the tab key mapping override and use `<C-n>` (control-n) to complete the current word. See `:help ins-completion`.

Comment: By your suggestion, I add `autocmd VimEnter * iunmap <TAB>` in my `.vimrc`, and `<TAB>`  key can work as I hope. Thanks.